# Can you use both @Given and @And for a certain step?

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin

I have several tests which share Step Definitions. For example:

```
Scenario: test1
  Given that the sky is blue
  And that the sun is up
  When I go outside
  Then I might get a sunburn

Scenario: test2
  Given that the sun is up
  When I go outside
  Then it will be light
```

Both steps "And that the sun is up" and "Given that the sun is up" are equal in their implementation.

What I would like is this:

```
@And("that the sun is up")
@Given("that the sun is up")
public void thatTheSunIsUp() {
    // Do some fancy and sunny things.
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work. How can I achieve the same, without having duplicate methods for equal steps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every step in cucumber is defined as a `Given`, `When` or `Then`, but in reality it's more like:

```
// ENTER PSUEDOCODE
@Step("that the sun is up")
public void thatTheSunIsUp() {
    // Do some fancy and sunny things.
}
```

The keywords are interchangeable, which allows for context as to whether it's a prerequisite (`Given`) an action under test (`When`) or an outcome (`Then`).

Defining it as you have originally (without the duplicate `@And` section), you would be able to use `Given`, `When`, `Then`, `And`, `But` and `*` in your feature file as the keyword, and cucumber's backend should match your step, but what you use for your definition should match up with it's intended use (as described in the previous paragraph)

Comment: `@Step` is not an available annotation under `cucumber.api.java.en` package ? I have same question, How to annotate the step-definition method in java file for a step which I want to use as `Given` in one scenario and as `And` in another scenario ?  
Do I have to create 2 method one `@Given` another `@And` with different method name but same code ?

Comment: @ThrowableException Note, I said Psuedocode - I believe the only annotations available are `@Given`, `@Then`, and `@When` - it's been a while since I last used the Java implementation - however, only one of the annotations is needed. `@And` and `@But` are not annotations to my knowledge

Answer (score 4):

You can't annotate the same method with the same text twice in cucumber. However, you can call a method annotated with @Given using `And` in your feature file.

So either remove the @And annotation, or change the text in one of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, however

Are you against using the @Repeatable function?

my understanding is you could use the @Given again with @Repeatable from Java8+.